# Jquery jAlert plugin: JAlert over jPrompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

having an issue- want to show jAlert() over jPrompt().

The jAlert shows up fine. But, its hiding the jPrompt. Can we show jAlert pop-up over jPrompt, keeping it as it is?

```
jPrompt('Please post your message','', 'Post Message', function(text) {

     if (text == null || text.length < 1) 
     {
         jAlert('Please enter text', 'Post Message');
     }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the callback you pass to prompt executes after the prompt is already closed, not when you press the okay button.

If you want a modal window that the user can enter some information into, I'd suggest switching from the third-party jAlert to the [official jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), as it provides much more flexibility.